# How to implement a template common for maps and sets?

Tags: c++, templates, set

I'm loading various data from database, and have already implemented a template-method:

```
template <typename R>
bool
loadMap(map<const string, R> &store, const char *query) {
{
...
      for (auto row : rows(query)) {
          store.insert(make_pair(row[0], R(row[1], row[2], ....));
      }
}
```

The method sends the `query` to the DB-server and populates the `store` with the results. The first column becomes the key of the map, and the rest of the fields form the value structure. That works.

However, in a couple of cases, the queries returns just *one* column -- which is stored in a `set` (or `unordered_set`) -- without any values associated with it.

Currently those cases are handled by methods of their own, and I'd like to extend my `loadMap`-function to these other types of containers -- perhaps, renaming it to `loadContainer`.

How would this new `loadContainer`'s declaration look, and how would it invoke the `store.insert()` with just the key, no values?

(I'm aware of the dodge of turning the set into a map with all values being empty, but I'd like to avoid that.)

Actually, I cannot even think of a way to handle `map` and `unordered_map` -- though the `insert` would be exactly the same, how would I declare such a function? The two map-types don't seem to have a common ancestor (nor "interface", to use a Java-term)...

Comment: You could use `map<const string, std::optional<R>>`

Comment: I was just about to put that comment in, but was beaten to it.  Use `std::optional<R>`.

Comment: Thank you both, but it'd still be a `map`, would not it? Not a `set` -- nor even an `unordered_map`...

Comment: At my work (with Java), we faced this problem and ended up with a core `template<Container> void queryAll(Container<T>&)` that did the real work, and then three helper wrappers: `List<T> queryAll()`, `T queryOneOrThrow()`, and `Optional<T> queryOneOrNone()` overloads.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Java has run-time type information (RTTI)! You can create new _classes_ on the fly, at run-time, and then create objects of these newly-created types for each SQL-query -- based on the names/types of the columns returned. In C++ there is no such (expensive) luxury, though...

Comment: @MikhailT.: Right, but we don't like RTTI, which is why we have the caller pass in the container in the core method I showed. What we did is 100% doable in C++.  Then again, this is C++, so maybe the entire concept would be better as an iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having solved the problem of [distinguishing between maps and sets](/questions/65472996/), I was able to implement different `insert`-functions for different container-types.

My `loadMap` templatized function is simply calling the `insert(store, key, value)` -- and the correct `insert` implementation is picked at compile time depending on the type of the `store`. (For sets, the `value` is ignored.)

Answer (score 2):

You might have overloads

```
template <typename R>
bool loadContainer(std::map<string, R> &store, const char *query) {
{
    // ...
    for (auto row : rows(query)) {
        store.insert(std::make_pair(row[0], R(row[1], row[2] /*, ...*/));
    }
    // ...
}

bool loadContainer(std::set<string> &store, const char *query) {
{
    // ...
    for (auto row : rows(query)) {
        store.insert(row[0]);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, to avoid overload, you might do (C++17)

```
template <typename Container>
bool loadContainer(Container& store, const char *query) {
{
    // ...
    for (auto row : rows(query)) {
        if constexpr (is_map<Container>::value) {
            using R = typename Container::mapped_type;
            store.insert(std::make_pair(row[0], R(row[1], row[2] /*, ...*/));
        } else {
            store.insert(row[0]);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

with appropriate traits as for example

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Enabler = void>
struct is_map : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_map<T, std::void_t<typename T::mapped_type>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: I wish, the `rows()` call really was as simple :) But, maybe, I ought to make it into an iterator of its own... Khm... Anyway, what about the `map` vs. `unordered_map`? Do these two types really require a separate method each too -- even if the code is _identical_?

Comment: You might still use SFINAE or c++20 concepts.

Comment: No, it has to work with `-std=gnu++0x` using g++-4.4

Comment: SFINAE works even pre-C++11, but we have generally to rewrite some utils provided in std post C++11.

Comment: @MikhailT. *No, it has to work with -std=gnu++0x using g++-4.4* -- [boost](https://www.boost.org/) could be your friend.

Comment: clang++ gives me an error -- constexpr if is a C++17 extension :(

Comment: @MikhailT.: You can use trait functions to implement the variable parts rather than constexpr if.

Comment: but then you have overloads and simple overload might be simpler than overloads with SFINAE.